# Managing Storage Spaces Direct in Windows Admin Center

Tags: storage-spaces-direct, windows-admin-center

I have a Hyper-V server, also running Windows Admin Center, let's call it `FISH`. That server is set up as gateway. On it, there are two storage pools, which can be managed via the Server Manager normally, and some VMs.

In Windows Admin Center, Storage Spaces (Direct) is not available in server management, and from what I gathered, I need to connect to a Cluster.

I have tried to add a cluster, but I am having issues. Using `FISH.local` appears to find the server/cluster, however using usernames `Administrator`, `FISH\Administrator` or `FISH.local\Administrator` yields the following error:

> Access was denied to "FISH.local". You can still add it to your connections list, but you'll need to provide administrator credentials to connect to the cluster.

In WAC settings it says I am signed in as "FISH\Administrator", so I am a bit at a loss. Does cluster management require a different kind of Administrator account/permissions?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Admin Center uses Powershell under the hood. That kind of architecture is known to work exceptionally when managing standalone servers. Still, it may cause issues due to the infamous "Kerberos Double Hop" specifics, especially when Windows Admin Center is running in gateway mode.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/ba-p/395463

While the blog by Ned Pyle describes how to work around the problem, the best approach for the clustered production environment is running Windows Admin Center in highly available mode as described below.

https://www.hyper-v.io/install-windows-admin-center-windows-failover-cluster/